# How to limit the number of active sessions a user can have

Tags: php

I am buiding a licence style system where a user can buy one or a number of licences. They can then log in to the system only once with each licence (similar to Spotify). So a user buys 2 licences. They can log in once in Firefox and once with Chrome. If they try to log in using IE the system will prompt/warn that they will be logged out of another session.

I understand a user could just use multiple instances of the same browser to gain access to multiple sessions/screens but thats fine. We are really only trying to stop users from using multiple devices (2+ separate PCs) if their licence restricts.

Any idea how I would go about this? Can I check session data from another instance or should I store the logins in a separate table and check against that?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO. But a basic solution would include unique IDs for each session issued to a user, and storing them with the user data. It would then be simple to check how many active sessions that user has currently, and to invalidate one at will.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. I will implement a unique ID to the session as you suggested. Seems simple enough.

Comment: 1. Get user IP address.
2. Set flag at sessions for the particular IP address.
3. If it crosses the limit, do { your statements }.